# Verbose build logs from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, build.gradle

How do I get a verbose log (including the command-line arguments to compiler and linker) when building with Android Studio?

I have just transitioned from Ant / Android.mk builds to Android-Studio builds.
With the old system, I was able to see how the compiler was evoked by doing:

```
$ ndk-build V=1
```

What would be the equivalent setting in Android Studio to accomplish this?
I have a suspicion that my project is building against the wrong GLES version (gles2 instead of gles3) and want to make sure by seeing the command line arguments to the linker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out you can make the build verbose by changing the build.gradle file as follows:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1"       
        }
    }
```

When using ndk-build instead of cmake, use this instead:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "V=1"
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no such configuration `arguments "V=1"` in the ndkBuild block
`

Comment: You need to put `externalNativeBuild` section inside `defaultConfig` section, if you are getting Gradle errors

Comment: I don't have a defaultConfig section, and the verbose option syntax above doesn't work if you put it at the root level of the file: Could not find method externalNativeBuild() for arguments [build_3oifztzr5n296zezo3h5iddmk$_run_closure1$_closure4@49771ff] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/NdkBuild there is no possibility to pass arguments.
But you can pass an the folder for outputs, which generates .json files

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            // Tells Gradle to put outputs from external native
            // builds in the path specified below.
            buildStagingDirectory "./outputs/ndk-build"
            path 'Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

So in my case in outputs/ndk-build/debug/json_generation_record.json the last "message" told me the error:

```
JSON generation completed with problem. Exception: Build command failed.
Error while executing process .... ndk-build.cmd ....
...
Android.mk:myLib-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file 
Android NDK: Check that ... exists  or that its path is correct 
...prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.\n"
```